# keyup/keydown vs input event - angular 2

Tags: angular

I am trying to capture all keyboard events for my autocomplete directive in angular 2. I have categorized it into 3 different types of events.

**1) keyup/keydown -> space , arrow up , arrowdown , enter , escape**

```
     @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])
      keyDownEvent(event: KeyboardEvent) { 

 switch (event.code) {
      // keycode 32
      case "Space" :
      //handle space event
        break;

        //keycode 38
      case "ArrowUp":
        //handle arrow up event
        break;

        //keycode 40
      case "ArrowDown":
        //handle arrow down event
        break;

        //keycode 13
      case "Enter":
        //handle enter 
        break;

        //keycode 27
      case "Escape":
        //handle escape event
        break;

      default :
        break;
    }
      }
```

**2) blur**

```
@HostListener('blur', ['$event'])
  bluEventHandler(event: any){
 }
```

**3) input** (all other keys on keyboard except what is mentioned in #1 and #2 like a-z ,A-z , especial characters etc)

????

I am not sure how to capture the input event. I am trying to convert my angular code to angular 2  and this is how it looks in angular 1

```
$(this.element).bind("keydown", function (event) {
}
 $(this.element).bind("input", function (event) {
}
 $(this.element).bind("blur", function (event) {
}
```

Comment: Should work the same. What's the problem?

Comment: update question

Comment: `@HostListener('input', ['$event'])` ;-) or `<input (input)="onInput($event)>`.

Comment: if I add @HostListener('input', ['$event']) , my "space" keyboard event is coming to @HostListener('input', ['$event'])  instead of  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event'])

Comment: So it's not the `input` that's not working, but the `keyup`? Perhaps `case "Space"` is not working as expected. Have you checked if `keyDownEvent()` or `keyUpEvent()` is called at all?

Comment: except space everything else is going to  @HostListener('window:keyup', ['$event']) . The problem with space going to input event is that I can't differentiate between 'space' and alphabet 'a' since there is not keycode or code present in the event object when it comes to input event handler. So I can't put a switch case there.

Comment: Seems to work fine for me https://plnkr.co/edit/G5H5b4Sm3mtOO4JPtf3L?p=preview or perhaps I don't understand what you try to accomplish

Comment: yeah it's working in your plunker. I will try again. If you can put your comment as answer, I will accept it. Thanks! :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the same way to listen to `input` like you do for `keyup`

```
@HostListener('input', ['$event'])
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/G5H5b4Sm3mtOO4JPtf3L?p=preview)